# ¿Cómo puedo poner un update de registro en php?

Tags: php, condiciones

buena noche.

brevemente, estoy trabajando con un contador de fechas en php conforme pasan los días el contador resta días de los 30 que están predeterminados, sin embargo, antes de llegar al ultimo día estoy intentando meter un update para que actualice los registros de un array pero no entra el update a pesar de que ya le puse un  if, cada que actualizo la pagina entra el update sin importar que falten más de 20 días.

la pregunta es, ¿Cómo puedo meter correctamente el update cuando falte 1 día de finalizar el periodo?

```
 if($row['Estado']=="Activo"){
     date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
      $fechaActual = date_create(date("Y-m-d"));
      $fechaFinal = date_create(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row['fecha_actual']) + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30)));      
      ($days = date_diff($fechaFinal, $fechaActual));


     $actualizar=$conexion->query("UPDATE pedidos SET Estado='Cancelado'
      WHERE id='$ids'"); 
    
      $diasFaltantes = (int)$days->format('%a');
       echo  '<td><span class="label label-default">Faltan '.$diasFaltantes. "finaliza";
 
      }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> la pregunta es, ¿Cómo puedo meter correctamente el update cuando falte
> 1 día de finalizar el periodo?

Tienes que poner un condicional que verifique si los días del intervalo son igual a `1` simplemente:

```
if ($days->days === 1) {
     $actualizar=$conexion->query("UPDATE pedidos SET Estado='Cancelado'
      WHERE id='$ids'");    
}
```

Comment: gracias era lo que me faltaba.